# How to test an async exception handler

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method `Task<Details> GetDetails(int number);`.

It's called from an async MVC controller:

```
        var details = _provider.GetDetails(input);
        Details details = null;
        try
        {
            details = await getDetails;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // SOME CODE THAT NEEDS TESTING
        }
```

Attempt to test in a custom, non-async testing framework.  GetDetails  method stubbed, using RhinoMocks:
`Provider.Stub(provider => provider.GetDetails(input)
            .Return(new Task<Details>(delegate { throw new Exception {}; }));`

The result is a deadlock of the unit test, it runs forever.
Any advice on how to fix this?

Comment: You need to use a framework that, at its core, is designed to work with asynchronous operations, knows about tasks, and how to work with them, etc.  If your testing framework simply isn't built to know about tasks then you won't be able to test proper asynchronous code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your deadlock is that you're creating a new `Task` without starting it.

For exceptions, it's better to use `TaskCompletionSource`:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Details>();
tcs.TrySetException(new Exception());
Provider.Stub(...).Return(tcs.Task);
```

However, as @Servy says, you won't get very far in testing asynchronous methods without a unit test framework that explicitly support async. It's doable but very inefficient and requires ceremony in every test method.

Comment: BTW I really like your blog. What blog engine it's running on?

Comment: @Test_me: It's generated static content, using (local) Jekyll with a simple Bootstrap-based template. It's open-source: https://github.com/StephenCleary/blog-stephencleary-dotcom